# Car powered ESP32 LED lights

Tags: arduino, led, batteries, esp32

I’m doing a project where I am using an ESP32 to power up some LEDs from a 12 V car battery. The way I have it set up is working, but because I am not too familiar with how current works I have some questions.

If we pretend that a car battery has 12 V, 120 A but I have it being converted to 5 V, how many amperes do I lose? How many might be being used?

Also, if I wanted to gain an ampere or so, if we can only use like pretend 5 A, how would I go about that? Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Note to the OP: you seems to have some fundamental misunderstandings about how electronic devices work with regard to their power supplies. I suggest you read through the answers in the linked duplicate to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Sure , I’ll read it over , thanks also for linking that to me any info I’ll take it ,        This is my first ever project so I’m honestly dumb with electronics like in the power and supply portion for making my own stuff but it’s something I find interesting thanks again 